# Why doesn't the Player.x and Player.y variables change?

Tags: c++

Edit #2: Ok, I did another *.cpp to check if the codes for Arrow Keys were right. Doing that, I noticed `keyPressed` variable in `detectKeyPressing()` had the wrong type of variable, so I changed it from `char` to `int` and changed the codes.

Once I did that, it worked. Now I have put the limits, so the `Player` cannot go outside the square. But I have another problem, the movement is too tough and if you press the keys too fast, the instructions run with a annoying delay. I know I should use either `Sleep(ms)` or `Delay(ms)`, but I don't know when I should use it.

This is the new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int detectKeyPressing() {
    // 0: Escape
    // 1: Enter
    //2: Up
    // 3: Left
    // 4: Down
    // 5: Right

    int keyPressed = 0;

    while (keyPressed != 27) {
        if (keyPressed == 0 || keyPressed == 224) {
            keyPressed = _getch(); //First value of _getch() when any of the arrow keys are pressed is "224", the next one is the code depending of which arrow you pressed
        }

        else if (keyPressed == 13) {
            return 1;
        }

        else {
            switch (keyPressed) {
                //Up
                case 72:
                    return 2;
                    break;
                //Left
                case 75:
                    return 3;
                    break;
                //Down
                case 80:
                    return 4;
                    break;
                //Right
                case 77:
                    return 5;
                    break;
                //Default
                default:
                    return -1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    return 0;
};


int mainMenu() {
    int enterPressed = 0;

    cout << "Press Enter to Begin, or ESC to exit" << endl;
    enterPressed = detectKeyPressing();

    system("cls");
    return enterPressed;
};

void draw(int playerX, int playerY) {
    //Player coordinates, made for testing
    cout << "Player.x = " << playerX << endl << "Player.y = " << playerY << endl;

    //The next 8 spaces go blank
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << endl;
    }

    //Square Limit Making
    //Top Limit
    for (int iw = 1; iw < 80; iw++) {
        cout << "-";
    }

    cout << endl;

    //Border limits and inside the Square
    for (int ih = 1; ih < 30; ih++) {
        //Left border
        cout << "|";

        //Inside the Square
        for (int iw = 1; iw < 78; iw++) {
            if (iw == playerX && ih == playerY) {
                cout << "a"; //This is supposed to be ♥ but I don't know how to put it in the screen with a cout
            }
            else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        //Right border
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

    //Bottom limit  
    for (int iw = 1; iw < 80; iw++) {
        cout << "-";
    }
}

int main() {
    //Hide cursor
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 1;
    cci.bVisible = FALSE;

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);

    //Variable Making
    int gameStarted = -1; // 1 if game is running, 0 if not
    //int t = 0; //Turn Counter, not useful for now

    Sleep(200); //Wait to get a new seed
    srand(time(NULL)); //Seed for rand()

    //Menu Loop, remember, 1 if game starts running, 0 if you exit
    while (gameStarted > 1 || gameStarted < 0) {
        gameStarted = mainMenu();
    }

    //Like Void Start() in Unity
    if (gameStarted == 1) {
        int pressedKey = -1; //Creating pressedKey at Start

        class Player {
            public:
                int life = 20;
                int accuracy = 80 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
                int damage = 5 + (accuracy / 10) + (rand() % 100) / 50;
                bool isAlive = true;
                int x = 39;
                int y = 24;
                int speed = 1;
        };

        class Enemy {
            public:
                int life = 100;
                int satisfaction = 0;
                bool isAlive = true;
                bool isSatisfied = false;
                int damage = 2 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
        };

        Player Player;
        Enemy Enemy;

        draw(Player.x, Player.y);

        //Like Void Update() in Unity
        while (gameStarted != 0) {
            pressedKey = detectKeyPressing(); // Save detectKeyPressing()'s return in pressedKey
            //Draw if proyectile is moving - not yet

            //Draw if player is moving (pay attention specially to this part)
            if (pressedKey == 0) {
                gameStarted = 0; //if ESC is pressed, exit the loop and exits
            }

            //If any of the Arrow Keys are pressed
            else if (pressedKey > 1 && pressedKey < 6) {
                switch (pressedKey) {
                    //Up
                    case 2:
                        Sleep(200);
                        if (Player.y == Player.speed) {
                            Player.y = Player.speed; //Top Limit
                        }
                        else {
                            Player.y -= Player.speed;
                        }
                        break;
                    //Left
                    case 3:
                        Sleep(200);
                        if (Player.x == Player.speed) {
                            Player.x = Player.speed; //Left Limit
                        }
                        else {
                            Player.x -= Player.speed;
                        }
                        break;
                        //Down
                    case 4:
                        Sleep(200);
                        if (Player.y == 30 - Player.speed) {
                            Player.y = 30 - Player.speed; //Bottom Limit
                        }
                        else {
                            Player.y += Player.speed;
                        }
                        break;
                        //Right
                    case 5:
                        Sleep(200);
                        if (Player.x == 78 - Player.speed) {
                            Player.x = 78 - Player.speed; //Right Limit
                        }
                        else {
                            Player.x += Player.speed;
                        }
                        break;
                };

                system("cls"); //Erase all
                draw(Player.x, Player.y); //Redraw everything, with Player.x or Player.y modified
            };
        };
    };

    return 0;
};
```

Edit #1: I fixed the mistakes you told me, here's the main function modified. It isn't working though.

```
int main(){
    //Hide cursor

    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 50;
    cci.bVisible = FALSE; //Changed "TRUE" to "FALSE"

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);

    //Variable Making
    int gameStarted = -1; // 1 if game is running, 0 if not
    //int t = 0; //Turn Counter, not useful for now

    Sleep(200); //Wait to get a new seed
    srand(time(NULL)); //Seed for rand()

    //Menu Loop, remember, 1 if game starts running, 0 if you exit
    while (gameStarted > 1 || gameStarted < 0) {
        gameStarted = mainMenu();
    }

    //Like Void Start() in Unity
    if (gameStarted == 1) {
        int pressedKey = -1; //Creating pressedKey at Start

        class Player {
            public:
                int life = 20;
                int accuracy = 80 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
                int damage = 5 + (accuracy / 10) + (rand() % 100) / 50;
                bool isAlive = true;
                int x = 39;
                int y = 24;
                int speed = 2;
        };

        class Enemy {
            public:
                int life = 100;
                int satisfaction = 0;
                bool isAlive = true;
                bool isSatisfied = false;
                int damage = 2 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
        };

        Player Player;
        Enemy Enemy;

        draw(Player.x, Player.y);

        //Like Void Update() in Unity
        while (gameStarted != 0) {
            pressedKey = detectKeyPressing(); //Save detectKeyPressing()'s return in pressedKey
            //Draw if proyectile is moving - not yet

            //Draw if player is moving (pay attention specially to this part)
            if (pressedKey == 0) {
                gameStarted = 0; //if ESC is pressed, exit the loop and exits
            }

            //If any of the Arrow Keys are pressed
            else if (pressedKey > 1 && pressedKey < 6) { 
                cout << "There's no problem in Else If statement"; //Couts made for testing
                switch (pressedKey) {
                    cout << "There's no problem in Switch statement";
                    //Up
                    case 2:
                        Player.y -= Player.speed;
                        cout << "You moved Up";
                        break;
                    //Left
                    case 3:
                        Player.x -= Player.speed; //Fixed Left movement
                        cout << "You moved Left";
                        break;
                    //Down
                    case 4:
                        Player.y += Player.speed;
                        cout << "You moved Down";
                        break;
                    //Right
                    case 5:
                        Player.x += Player.speed;
                        cout << "You moved Right";
                        break;
                };
                //system("cls"); //Erase all
                //draw(Player.x, Player.y); //Redraw everything, with Player.x and Player.y supposedly modified
            };
        };
    };

    return 0;
};
```

Initial Post: I'm trying to do something like an Undertale normal fight and now I'm doing the "dodging attacks" part, but I'm stuck at making the player move (Yep, that "a") because it didn't update when I press an arrow key (for movement). It is supposed to draw, and put the Player in Player.x and Player.y, so I did something in main() to edit these variables depending on the arrow key you pressed, and then erase and re-draw with the Player.x or Player.y modified.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int detectKeyPressing(){
    // 0: Escape
    // 1: Enter
    // 2: Up
    // 3: Left
    // 4: Down
    // 5: Right

    char keyPressed = 0;

    while (keyPressed != 27){
        if(keyPressed == 0){
            keyPressed = _getch();
        }

        else if(keyPressed == 13){
            return 1;
        }

        else{
            switch (keyPressed) {
                //Up
                case 65:
                    return 2;
                    break;
                //Left
                case 68:
                    return 3;
                    break;
                //Down
                case 66:
                    return 4;
                    break;
                //Right
                case 67:
                    return 5;
                    break;
                //Default
                default: 
                    return -1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
return 0;
};

int mainMenu(){
    int enterPressed = 0;

    cout << "Press Enter to Begin, or ESC to exit" << endl;
    enterPressed = detectKeyPressing();

    system("cls");
    return enterPressed;
};

void draw(int playerX, int playerY) {
    //Player coordinates, made for testing
    cout << "Player.x = " << playerX << endl << "Player.y = " << playerY << endl;
    //The next 8 spaces go blank
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << endl;
    }
    //Square Limit Making
    //Top Limit
    for (int iw = 1; iw < 80; iw++) {
        cout << "-";
    }

    cout << endl;

    //Border limits and inside the Square
    for (int ih = 1; ih < 30; ih++) {
        //Left border
        cout << "|";
        //Inside the Square
        for (int iw = 1; iw < 78; iw++) {
            if (iw == playerX && ih == playerY){
                cout << "a"; //This is supposed to be ♥ but I don't know how to put it in the screen with a cout
            }
            else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        //Right border
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    //Bottom limit  
    for (int iw = 1; iw < 80; iw++) {
        cout << "-";
    }
}

int main(){
    //Hide cursor

    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 50;
    cci.bVisible = TRUE;

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);

    //Variable Making
    int gameStarted = -1; // 1 if game is running, 0 if not
    //int t = 0; //Turn Counter, not useful for now

    Sleep(200); //Wait to get a new seed
    srand(time(NULL)); //Seed for rand()

    //Menu Loop, remember, 1 if game starts running, 0 if you exit
    while (gameStarted > 1 || gameStarted < 0) {
        gameStarted = mainMenu();
    }

    //Like Void Start() in Unity
    if (gameStarted == 1) {
        class Player {
            public:
                int life = 20;
                int accuracy = 80 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
                int damage = 5 + (accuracy / 10) + (rand() % 100) / 50;
                bool isAlive = true;
                int x = 39;
                int y = 24;
                int speed = 2;
        };

        class Enemy {
            public:
                int life = 100;
                int satisfaction = 0;
                bool isAlive = true;
                bool isSatisfied = false;
                int damage = 2 + (rand() % 100) / 20;
        };

        Player Player;
        Enemy Enemy;

        draw(Player.x, Player.y);

        //Like Void Update() in Unity
        while (gameStarted != 0) {

            //Draw if proyectile is moving - not yet

            //Draw if player is moving (pay attention specially to this part)
            if (detectKeyPressing() == 0) {
                gameStarted = 0; //if ESC is pressed, exit the loop and exits
            }

            //If any of the Arrow Keys are pressed
            else if (detectKeyPressing() > 1 && detectKeyPressing() < 6) { 
                switch (detectKeyPressing()) {
                    //Up
                    case 2:
                        Player.y -= Player.speed;
                        break;
                    //Left
                    case 3:
                        Player.x += Player.speed;
                        break;
                    //Down
                    case 4:
                        Player.y += Player.speed;
                        break;
                    //Right
                    case 5:
                        Player.x += Player.speed;
                        break;
                };
                system("cls"); //Erase all
                draw(Player.x, Player.y); //Redraw everything, with Player.x and Player.y supposedly modified 
            };
        };
    };

    return 0;
};
```

I did a few tests and it seems that the else if in "//If any of the Arrow Keys is Pressed" part isn't running but I don't know why.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide. Sorry if anything isn't well written, I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: You should save your return before checking the conditions within your loop. The way you’re doing it will trigger your function each time an if condition is checking.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think this is the main problem, but in your `main` function's `switch` statement, do a `-=` to move left. Right now, your right and left movement is the same because both cases have the same line `Player.x += Player.speed;`.

Comment: No usage of a debugger?  You can't write code like this and hope everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have this comment
`//Draw if proyectile is moving - not yet` add a variable to save your pressed key, something like

`int pressedKey = detectKeyPressing();`

Then, use that variable to check which condition is met within your `if-else`.

What’s happening is that you’re calling your function, thus asking/waiting for an input each time a condition is being checked.

Comment: Edited the post with the mistakes you found, already solved (but the main issue isn't solved yet). I'm going to make a new *.cpp file just to be sure if the program really recognizes when I press the arrow keys.

Comment: Ok, I did the test and the program couldn't recognize the arrow keys, so I'm going to check the `switch` statement in `detectKeyPressing()`.

Comment: Fixed Movement Issue, now the "a" can move. Better explained in post (Edit #2).